# \api\data\v9.0 is failing with error 401 unauthorized in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, powerapps

Thread Name:Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start:2022-11-14 15:38:43 GMT
Load time:56
Connect Time:42
Latency:56
Size in bytes:1472
Sent bytes:2669
Headers size in bytes:1472
Body size in bytes:0
Sample Count:1
Error Count:1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""):
Response code:401
Response message:Unauthorized

HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType:
DataEncoding: null

Response Header
Connection: keep-alive
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.5
prefer: odata.include-annotations="*"
x-ms-sw-tenantid:
x-ms-user-agent:
clienthost: Browser
x-ms-client-session-id:
Accept: application/json
x-ms-source-id:
x-ms-sw-objectid:
x-ms-correlation-id:
content-type: application/json
x-ms-app-id:

I tried applying Cookie Manager and Authorization Manager but the code is failing everytime.

Comment: What kind of auth mechanism is application using? Auth manager does not support everything out there. Also you can share some screenshots from your auth manager config element.

Answer (score 0):

As per [HTTP Status Code 401 description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401):

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) `401 Unauthorized` response status code indicates that the client request has not been completed because it **lacks valid authentication credentials for the requested resource.**
>
> This status code is sent with an HTTP [`WWW-Authenticate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/WWW-Authenticate) response header that contains information on how the client can request for the resource again after prompting the user for authentication credentials.

So you either need to provide proper [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header via [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-header-manager) or again properly configure the HTTP Authorization Manager to generate the header for you.